# Discrete Cosine Transformation formula disparity

Tags: algorithm, math, matlab, signal-processing, dct

Well, I was programming something that required the use of DCT. I found 2 resources for the DCT formula:

[Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f21-16366.html)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform)

Initially I used the wikipedia version of DCT-II. In the DCT-II section of wiki page, it is written that some authors further multiply the X0 term by 1/√2 and multiply the resulting matrix by an overall scale factor, which makes the DCT-II matrix orthogonal, but breaks the direct correspondence with a real-even DFT of half-shifted input. And the mathworks site does this only.

What is this property being talked about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive that they are trying to say that that are concerned about making the DCT-II transform matrix a [unitary matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix). It is nice from a signal processing standpoint to have a unitary matrix because when we transform the signal back to its original domain, we are not adding any more power into the signal.

However, the 1-D DFT:

[image: 1-D DFT]

can be rewritten in terms of sines and consies (using [Euler's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity)). If the input is a real-even signal, the even terms of the DFT will correspond to the terms of the DCT. Some people like to simplify their algorithms by simply taking the DFT of a signal, and only concentrating on the even terms.